# Passing Parameters to upload_to Parameter in Django File Upload

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I am using the following post to upload files in Django: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/01/how-to-upload-files-with-django.html.

In the post, it mentions that the upload_to parameter can be a callable that returns a string. In the example provided, the callable accepts two parameters, instance and filename as follows:

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

At what point and how do I pass parameters to upload_to? I am using 
    form.save(commit=True)

to persist form values to the database. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to explicitly provide any parameters. In the model declaration 'upload_to' is the reference of a function, which upon calling automatically receives the parameters. Here 'instance' is the database row for your object and 'filename' is generated by django model.